# How to create a SESSION variable without giving it a value? [php]

Tags: php, session

Basicaly my problem is the following:

I'm trying to create a session variable
so that something like this can happen

```
if(username == false) 
{
  $_SESSION['error messages'] = 'username missing';
}
```

The problem is that, while there are no errors, I want  $_SESSION['error messages'] to be empty.
But if I dont do something like this:

```
$_SESSION['error messages'] = 'garbage';
if(username == false) 
{
  $_SESSION['error messages'] = 'username missing';
}
```

It says that $_SESSION['error messages'] is not defined

How can I have this variable empty until I need it?

Thank you

Comment: why not set it to "" when you dont want any data in it?

Comment: I think you have to specify your question more, i don't get it!

Comment: you have a variable assignment (**=**) in the if condition instead of a condition (**==**). that's probably why you're not seeing the session variable.

Comment: @NoLiver92 , because if I set it like that, the red square in which the message appears stays there

Comment: @Rizier123 , I'm sorry if I confused you, but I really dont know how else I can specify more: an error 'Undifined index' appears, if I dont give some value to $_SESSION['error messages'] in the beggining of my script. But I only want it to have a value if there is an error, otherwise it should be empty, not even with a value like ''

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky  , that was a typing error, but thank you anyway

Comment: @manuelmourato Try something like this when you print it: `echo (isset($_SESSION["error messages"])? $_SESSION["error messages"]: "");` does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to *save* an error message, use the following:

```
if (empty($username)) {
    $_SESSION['error messages'][] = 'username missing';
}
```

It is nicer to keep an array of error messages. That way, if you have multiple errors, you can easily loop trough them, count them, ect.

Then, when you want to display the error messages, do the following.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error messages']) && is_array($_SESSION['error messages'])) {
  foreach ($_SESSION['error messages'] as $errorMessage) {
     // Do something with the error message, for instance:
     printf ("The following error occured: <em>%s</em><br>", $errorMessage);
  }

  // Next, clear the error messages so that they do not pop up on the next page request.
  unset($_SESSION['error messages']);
}
```

Wrap the code that uses `$_SESSION['error messages']` in [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) makes sure you won't get the error message about the index not being defined.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below

```
if(username==false) {
    $_SESSION['error messages']='username missing';
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I don't the the username is a constant

Comment: @Rizier123 Corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Init your session variable like this

```
$_SESSION['error messages'] = null;
if($username == false) {
    $_SESSION['error messages'] = 'username missing';
}
```

You can init any other kind of variables not just session ones

Answer (score 2):

To check if the `$_SESSION['error message']` is set use this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['error message'])){
    $_SESSION['error message'] = '';
}
```

will create an empty session variable if its not already set.

**But** you're probably accessing this session variable somewhere in your code while you *don't* need it, so only access the variable when you DO need it, having empty variables everywhere isn't really neat.

You're better off changing your code so that it wont try to access something that isn't set and also isn't needed, instead of setting empty variables to "hack" your code so it works.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$_SESSION['error messages'] = 'garbage';
if(username == false) 
{
  $_SESSION['error messages'] = 'username missing';
}
```

you missed == in if condition.